# Modify value of a variable in a javascript function using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-debugging

I could manually put a breakpoint in the code, then modify the value and resume the execution. Is it feasible to automate this through chrome extension?

```
'"dfffeiijig"': function(e, t, a) {
    "use strict";
    function n(e) {
        return e && e.__esModule ? e : {
            "default": e
        }
    }
    function i(e, t, a) {
        return (0,
        l.aesCbcEncrypt)(e, new Uint8Array(a)).then(function(e) {
            return new d.HmacSha256(t).sign(e).then(function(t) {
                return p.build(t, e).readBuffer()
            })
        })
    }
```

I want to modify 'a' in the function.

Comment: If this `dfffeiijig` property is accessible from a global variable like foo.bar.dfffeiijig, you can overwrite it [in the page context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/). Otherwise you'll have to use chrome.debugger API to replicate what you're doing in devtools.